# VS code typescript not compile correctly

Tags: angular

I'm using VS code for angular 4, but for every small change (in TS and html files) I get ng serve instead of re compiling. it go over all modules, percent by percent.

Comment: Are you using shortcut key(Ctrl + s) for save changes?I don't understand, If "ng serve" executing every changes so you didn't face the issue like 'Port 4200 is already in use...'?

Comment: yes, I'm using Ctrl+s, I get message in the terminal - compiling... but it run like build - go over all files and compiling.

Comment: It would be good if you share a screenshot..

Comment: I can't sory... but I'll expand the problem:
1. it run over all modules (percent by percent)
2.in case I have error compilation, even I fix it, the red message in the trminal stay, and I have to terminat batch job ang run ng serve or npm start to re build. it doesn't compile automatical